# include bash script arguments when submitting via bsub

Tags: bash, shell, batch-processing

I have the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash --login

#BSUB -q q_ab_mpc_work
#BSUB -J psipred
#BSUB -W 01:00
#BSUB -n 64
#BSUB -o psipred.out
#BSUB -e psipred.err
module load compiler/gnu-4.8.0
module load R/3.0.1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

code=${HOME}/Phd/script_dev/rfpipeline.sh
MYPATH=$HOME/Phd/script_dev/
cd ${MYPATH}
${code} myfile.txt
```

in which I can use bsub to submit program to cluster:

```
bsub < myprogram.sh
```

however I change the last line in my program to:

```
${code} $1
```

where I use a command line argument to specify the file, how can I pass this to bsub?

I have tried:

```
bsub < myprogram.sh myfile.text
```

however bsub will not accept `myfile.text` as a bash parameter.

I have also tried

```
bsub <<< myprogram.sh myfile.text
./myprogram.sh myfile.text | bsub
bsub "sh ./myprogram.sh myfile.text"
```

what do I need to do?

Comment: I think you just need: `bsub myprogram.sh myfile.text`.

Comment: @meuh - technically this runs, but the job fails. If I am quick and use `bjobs` I can see it has been submitted, then see that it has been run, but then instantly I get "no unfinished jobs found". the output I expect `mkdir test` shows no new folder called `test` so I assume it hasn't worked.

Comment: you should have a stderr log file somewhere. try adding `set -x` in the script to track which commands get executed too.

Comment: @ meuh - I can use `#BSUB -oo logfile.txt` to see the log. it tells me exactly the script that was run.

Answer (score 3):

Can I answer my own question?

It seems that I can use sed to modify the file on the fly. My original file is now:

```
#!/bin/bash --login

#BSUB -q q_ab_mpc_work
#BSUB -J psipred
#BSUB -W 01:00
#BSUB -n 64
#BSUB -o psipred.out
#BSUB -e psipred.err
module load compiler/gnu-4.8.0
module load R/3.0.1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

code=${HOME}/Phd/script_dev/rfpipeline.sh
MYPATH=$HOME/Phd/script_dev/
cd ${MYPATH}
${code} myfile
```

and I wrote a bash script, `sender.sh` to both modify the variable `myfile` with a command line argument, and send the modified file off to bsub:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "s/myfile/$1/g" < myprogram.sh | bsub
```

being careful to use double quotes so that bash does not read `$` literally. I then simply run `./sender.sh jobfile.txt` which works!

Hope this helps anybody.

Answer (score 2):

This answer should resolve your problem:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144518/pass-argument-to-script-then-redirect-script-as-input-to-bsub

Just pass the script with arguments at the end of the bsub command.

Ex.
example.sh

`#!/bin/bash
export input=${1}
echo "arg input: ${input}"`

bsub command:

`bsub [bsub args] "path/to/example.sh arg1"`

Comment: But this does not work for specifying arguments in a Bash script file. When using a Bash script file one must use a redirect. E.g. `bsub < demo.bsub`.